# Flutter - Detect Tap on the Screen that is filled with other Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, gesture

I am trying to detect a tap on the screen. I've tried multiple variation of using the `GestureDetector` but that just leads to the app detecting tap on the **child element** and **not the screen**.

Here is the code:

```
class QQHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('QuoteQuota'),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('Tapped'),
          child: QQBody(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QQBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, World!'
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output: "tapped" printed when I click "Hello, World!".

Expected Output: "tapped" printed when I click anywhere on the screen with Text in the Center.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `GestureDetector's` `behavior` property and pass `HitTestBehavior.opaque` to it, which recognizes entire screen and detects the tap when you tap anywhere on the screen.

```
body: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () => print('Tapped'),
          child: QQBody(),
        ),
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi @Darshan, I have a similar sort of requirement. I want the QQBody to be displayed when I tap anywhere on the screen instead of printing 'Tapped' within the console. I'm new to Flutter and not sure how can I achieve that. I did try replacing print with QQBody but it didn't work. Could you please suggest what needs to be done. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Like Darshan said, you can trigger Tap by wrapping the body inside a Gesture detector like this...

```
body: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () => print('Tapped'),
          child: QQBody(),
        ),
```

Also in some cases, you may need to avoid trigger clicking on other widgets while tapping anywhere in body. That can be solved by using `IgnorePointer` Widget

```
body: GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        print('This will click');
      },

      // -------- No Widget below tree will be trigger click.

      child: IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: ClassLibrary.selected != null ? true : false,
        child: TabBarView(
          children: [
                   ...
```

Comment: What do you do if `QQBody` isn't full screen but is just something in the center of a blank screen? How do you go about capturing a gesture anywhere on the screen then?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very easy with `TapRegion`

```dart
TapRegion(
    onTapInside: (event) => print('tapped'),
    child: SomeChild(),
)
```

It also have another useful method called `onTapOutside` in case you need that too.

Answer (score 1):

@Darshan is a correct answer but I want to add something to it. I wanted a trigger whenever the screen is touched and onTap only reacts to a tap (no slide). However that behaviour can be achieved bij adding onTapCancel

```
body: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () => print('Tapped'),
          onTapCancel: () => print('Touched but not tapped'),
          child: QQBody(),
        ),
```

Comment: I think handling onTapCancel and onTap gives the best results in implementing this usecase

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code--

```
class QQHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('QuoteQuota'),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('Tapped'),

          child: Container(
          height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stack`: put layers on top of each other.
The good thing about `Stack` is you can arrange stack order as you want.
If you want to do something as the screen is touched, and do something else if a button on the screen is touched, you can easily do it with stack by putting the button on top of `GestureDetector`.

The following is your example:

```
class QQHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('QuoteQuota'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          // Bottom to Top order
          children: <Widget> [
            QQBody(),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print('Tapped'),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QQBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, World!'
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That does work but nothing else on the screen can be tapped anymore because you have the GestureDetector on top.